# I am trying to get the latitude and longitude using mapbox but it always just print my initial location and not the updated center of camera location

Tags: flutter, mapbox

I'm trying to get the the longitude and latitude of the map using mapbox, but instead of getting the lat, lng of the current camera location it only prints the intial camera location

```
      late MapboxMapController _mapController;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
          body: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: MapboxMap(
                  accessToken: dotenv.env['MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN'],
                  initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                    target: LatLng(37.7749, -122.4194),
                    zoom: 11.0,
                  ),
                  onMapCreated: (controller) {
                    setState(() {
                      _mapController = controller;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.location_on_outlined),
              onPressed: () async {
                // Get the center point of the map
                LatLng? center = _mapController.cameraPosition?.target;
                // Do something with the picked location
                print('Picked location: $center');
              },
              label: const Text('Pick Location')));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using web version of Mapbox, I think You need get it from Event not from your controller.

I found this package, maybe help you.
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-maps-flutter

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).